# Image relative path stop working after packages upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I had an angular2 application, built with angular-cli (v 1.0.0), webpack2.

Inside a component I could reference an image:

```
<div class="country-flag">
  <img [src]="src/assets/flags/32/jp.png" [width]="flagIconSize" [height]="flagIconSize" />
</div>
```

Images are stored inside the default assets folder:

```
Root
 |--src
     |--app
     |--assets
         |--flags
              |--32
                 |-- ...png
```

and registered in the .angular-cli.json file:

```
 "apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ]
```

The images were displayed without any problem. However today I updated the packages to the latest version:

- angular      4.1.2
- angular-cli  1.0.3

From this moment on, I get 404 for every image inside the assets folder, even if the path looks correct:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/src/assets/flags/32/jp.png 404 (Not Found)
```

**Is anything changed with the newest releases about path resolution?**

Comment: Shouldn't the correct path be without `src`? Try with `http://localhost:4200/assets/flags/32/jp.png`

Comment: That was it! I was absolutely sure to have tried that way too, but probably the page was simply not refreshed. Thanks

Comment: I will post an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path is without `src`

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/flags/32/jp.png
```